# Pass PHPvariable in Ajax to Javascript then back to PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am pulling up an array in ajax to create a table.  I set a variable where if a permit is required, it brings up a pop-up via Javascript.  I want to pass the Order ID to the pop up so that the person can continue on to the job.  The variable is in the Ajax and I need a way to pass it all the way through to the pop up.

AJAX:

```
if($row['alert'] == '1') {$stat = 'label-awaitingPermits'; 
                          $nav = '<a href="javascript:;" onClick="openFileUploader();" class="btn btn-danger" data-box="#permit-alert">'.$row['po'].'</a>';}
```

*The $row['po'] is the Order ID*

JS:

```
function openFileUploader(){$("#permit-alert").modal('show'); }
```

HTML:

```
<p>This job requires more documents in order for the permits to be filed.  Please provide these documents so that we can continue to process your order</p>
                            <p>Continue to Job<?php echo $row['po'];?></p>
```